# How to make Data Structure

Tags: chisel

I want to make **data structure** similar to C-language's support, in the Chisel3 description.

```
class Tablel(DataWidth: Int, NumLinks: Int) extends Bundle {
        val valid       = Reg(Bool())
        ...
}
```

in other class references it:

```
val Tab = Vec(NumEntries, Table(DataWidth, NumLinks))
```

Error is;

```
not found: value Table
```

Yes, it is because of class.

I do not yet understand about how describe data structure which does not use **class** declaration.
Can anyone point out it?

Answer (score 1):

In your example the word `Tablel` has an extra 'l' at the end.
Also to create an instance of a class you must use the `new` operator.

```
val tab = Vec(NumEntries, new Table(DataWidth, NumLinks))
```

I would also recommend following typical Scala formatting rules.
For example, variables should be begin with a lower case letter.
It will help you read others' code, and for others to read yours.

And as far as your more general question of how to create data structure, the answer for Chisel is to use `Bundle`, `Record`, and `Vec`. So you are on the right track.

Comment: Markley-san, many thanks. Now, my code is **[info] Done packaging.**.